# Recording data with WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, unity-game-engine, ipc

This is a question of design. I have read numerous different things about IPC between two C# applications, but don't feel like I have reached a satisfactory answer for my use case, yet.

In my 1st application I have an object that already exists that will change frequently every few milliseconds. I am trying to attach this to a game programmed with Unity3d (-> 2nd application). According to an earlier question at stackoverflow, It seems that serialisation is not appropriate as I would essentially be serializing/deserialzing the object every few milliseconds for no good reason. This brought me to WCF Services: The 1st application acts as host and the 2nd application (Unity program) acts as client. Does this make sense, so far?

Next, I want to record all data that I send from the 1st to the 2nd application. The initial goal here is that the 2nd application should be able to be supplied with data recorded in an earlier session. The purpose of this is mainly for developmental issues, when new data from the 1st application may not be available.

Can I use WCF to record and play back data (i.e. an entire data stream), which is exchanged between two applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To record every output from WCF you could implement a custom Logger (eg. nlog or log4net) that save information into any custom data storage (SqlServer, Mongo, Raven DB depends on your need)

### pseudo code

```
//[OperationContractAttribute]
    public int[] GetUnitPosition(string guid)
    {
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        //calculate something..

        //then Log this information 
        Logger.Info("position", guid, x, y); //save this into any DB

        return new[] {x, y};
    }
```

Then to retrieve the saved data. just implement another WCF service that query historical data from the log storage.

Comment: Thank you! So, do you think WCF is the right thing to use in my case? Can you point me to a good book/tutorial that gives me further insights to this topic? I assume that a general book about .NET or WCF will probably not cover this...